# maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.9 missing from Nexus repository

Tags: maven, nexus

I am new to working with Maven and Nexus.

I installed Maven on one Unix host for my project and a Nexus repository on another Unix host. I've configured my Maven settings to use the Nexus repository on the other machine. It seems to be working fine and the required artifacts/plugins are getting downloded from the Nexus repository. But a plugin named `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:pom:2.9` seems to be missing from the Nexus repository. I checked the Nexus repository manually and this `maven-surefire-plugin-2.9.jar` file is not present there, although this plugin's previous and new versions are present.

Now the problem seems to be that Nexus is not able to connect to the Internet, so I'll have to manually copy this jar file to the required location in the public repository along with its other versions.

Can someone tell me the steps to do so? I have downloded the jar and its pom file from the Internet, but I don't know how to put it in the required location with Nexus.

Comment: To cut the long story short... Nexus is proxy server so you need to be able to proxy at least the Central Repository. You need to get it hooked up to the internet if necessary by whitelisting it on a proxy server or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would turn into an endless story to put all artifacts manually into Nexus. The purpose of the repository proxy is to retrieve them and cache them. If it has no internet access that makes it a bit work intense rather than to simplify life.

What I would do: do a `mvn clean install dependency:go-offline` on a machine that has internet access and then copy the local repository into the nexus releases or thridparty repository and let it re-index via the web-gui.

That seems to be the easiest way. There is an upload feature in the nexus gui but if you do that artifact by artifact that will take a week...

since the nexus storage structure is 1:1 identical to what you see locally you can just copy the directory structures.

Comment: You do not need to reindex if you do not use the search UI. But after you copy the artifacts into a repository, you should run the task that rebuilds the maven metadata for that repository.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the prompt response! Much appriciated!

I have now compiled the project in my local machine which had the internet connection, so now I have the local repository with me.. so what would be the next step? to copy over the repository in the filesystem of nexus host?

Comment: yes. nexus creates a "sonatype-work" directory in the home directory of the user that runs nexus. in there are the repositories (one folder per repository). you can copy your local repository into the releases repository. make sure the folder structure is correct.

Comment: Be careful about doing this. A local repository is a mixture of snapshot and release artifacts and as such has to be migrated into Nexus twice. Once as release and once a snapshot repo.

Comment: I did copy over the artifaxts in there, and the errors with missing artifacts is now vanished, only to give me some more weird error :(

Now I am getting the error:
**
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile (default) on project KohlsCustomUI-presentation: Execution default of goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2:compile failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.4.2 at specified path /data/tibco/tibcojre64/1.6.0/../lib/tools.jar **

Comment: So after getting the above error I hae copied over the jar tools-1.4.2.jar in the public repository at the path /data/sonatype/sonatype-work/nexus/storage/central/com/sun/tools 
in the nexus filesystem and I can see this jar now through url, but my build in jenkins is still failing by giving the same error.. :( Any idea ?

Comment: that looks more like an issue with the JAVA_HOME variable or the installed JDK and not like a maven/nexus problem